# Проблема в двумерном массиве с целочисленными

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дан целочисленный двумерный массив, размерности n х m. Выяснить, какое число встречается в какой строке раньше — положительное или отрицательное.

нужно сделать функцию, не знаю с чего начать, помогите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

просто сравнивайте первый не нуль с нулем

```
def func(arr):
        return [(lambda x: x[-1]>0 if x else None)(filter(lambda x: x!=0, x)) for x in arr]

# если не 0 нет, вернет None    
func([[-1,1,-1],[1,-1,1]])
# [False, True]
```

Comment: return [x[0]>0 for x in arr]
можете объяснить, что значит эта строчка?

Comment: тоже самое  `r = []; for x in arr: r.append(x[0]>0);`

Comment: а 0 положительное или отрицательное ? @splash58

Comment: @splash58 это намек на ошибку

Comment: че намекать-то - напишите правильно

Answer (score 0):

Для всех вариантов

```
def func(arr):
    for a in arr:
        if a:
            return a > 0

def func2(arr):
    return [func(line) for line in arr]

res_str = {True: "Положительное", False: "Отрицательное", None: "Все нули"}





for x in func2([
    [1,2,3,-2],
    [-1,2,-3,-2],
    [0,2,-3,-2],
    [0,0,0,0],
]): 
    print(res_str[x])
```